# From an iFrame (php result form script): hide a div in parent

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

Context: I preview sendform results in an iFrame - of course, submit button is placed on parent page. All pages are on same domain.

I like (under conditions and from within an iFrame) to hide the submit button.

On parent page:

```
function hidesubmit() {
    $('#submitdiv').hide();   // hide button
    };

<iframe class="iframe_" frameborder="0" name="preview" onload="resizeIframe(this);" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

On php script (within the iFrame) I have this line that does not work

```
window.parent.hidesubmit();
```

On parent page (added) :

```
        <div class="preview" id="preview">
      <iframe class="iframe_" frameborder="0" name="preview" onload="resizeIframe(this);" scrolling="no"></iframe>
     <div id="animated" style="text-align:center; display:block;" ><img src="/templates/Gazette/Images/animateround.gif" width="124" height="124" vspace="5" /></div>
```

Order / Commandez via ✉  (%%GLOBAL_Protocol%%)

```
      <div class="espacesubmit" id="submitPhoneOnly">
        <button class="buttonsubmit" name="_Commande" onclick="return checkform();" type="submit">
          Order via Phone only / Commande par Tél. uniquement<br />
```

(You may submit to receive a copy / Vous pouvez soumettre pour recevoir une copie)

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with parent function call. Are you sure that line in framed page is executed?

Comment: @mesutozer, I am quite sure yes; Here is the code :
    if (($name == '') || ($email == '') || ($tel == ''))
{$boutonnosubmityet = '<div id="nosubmityet"><button class="ButtonsVerifier" name="_NoSubmit">
              Missing - Info - Manquante<br/>Your information
            </button>
          </div>';
window.parent.hidesubmit();
}

Comment: I think I understand your issue, let me guess with an answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can only act on the parent if it's on the same domain. (See [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOP)).

If it is on the same domain, then you need to use `window.top`.

eg :

```
window.top.hidesubmit();
```

Another way to do it would be to add an event "onsubmit()" on the parent form as such :

```
<form name='myForm' action='...' method='...' onsubmit='hidesubmit();return true;'>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Stop using iframe

Seriously.

- It's old! VERY old!
- It's not a good pratice.
- It's hard to manipulate

And you don't need that. You just don't know that.

### Alternative

Use a simple **ajax request** for get whatever you want and **write** in your page

- Call the page what do you want
- Get the result (pure html without header/footer, just the content)
- Write in you html page using `.html()` / `.append()`

### Possible solution

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent

```
ẃindow.parent.hidesubmit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to execute a javascript call from within PHP. You need to enclose it in a script block like:

```
$boutonnosubmityet = '<div id="nosubmityet"><button class="ButtonsVerifier"
name="_NoSubmit"> Missing - Info - Manquante<br/>Your information </button></div>'
. '<script type="text/javascript">window.parent.hidesubmit();</script>';
```

Comment: Do you have script tags surrounding "function hidesubmit() {" in parent page?

Comment: Yes: <script  type="text/javascript">
function hidesubmit() {
    $('#submitdiv').hide();   // hide button
 };
</script>

Comment: Make sure the div you are trying to hide has id="submitdiv" attribute (you did not give that part of the code)

Comment: It does yes. The solutions presented above (not using iFrame) is a bit complicated for me!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show more information like the HTML containing the div to be hidden etc..

Comment: Although I prefer specific answers to solve described questions instead of generic suggestions, I should admin other answers above would help you better in long term.

Comment: I cannot see a div with id = submitdiv, is it still not shown?

Comment: Sorry for a reason, It did not paste! here it is :<div id="submitdiv" style="margin:10px;">
            <button id="submit" class="buttonsubmit" name="_Commande" onclick="return checkform();" type="submit" style="background-color:#%%GLOBAL_Color1%%;">
             Order / Commandez via &#9993; </br> (%%GLOBAL_Protocol%%)
            </button>
          </div>

Comment: It still seems to me that window.parent.hidebutton() line is never executed. You can verify this by adding an alert like: <script type="text/javascript> window.parent.hidebutton(); alert(1); </script>... If you cannot see alert box, then hidebutton function is not executed

Comment: You are right, it is not executed. Let me investigate, I will keep you posted! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! I place the javascript funtion somewhere else!!! Thank you, it's solved.